# Cron run script, but don't work

Tags: tomcat, cron

I have a problem with my Cron task.

I have a script:

```
wget --http-user=admin --http-password=admin http://my_adress/manager/text/reload?path=/myApp
echo "Restart app" >> /opt/tomcat/webapps/restartLog.txt
```

I add to crontab -e

```
*/1 * * * * root /bin/bash /opt/tomcat/webapps/autoRestart.sh
```

Well,  nothing happens: /

In the syslog I normally it is invoked every minute, but not created
the file with the logs (restartLog.txt) and the application is not restarted.

```
May 22 13:08:01 myApp/USR/SBIN/CRON[5518]: (root) CMD (root /bin/bash /opt/tomcat/webapps/autoRestart.sh)
May 22 13:09:01 myApp/USR/SBIN/CRON[5526]: (root) CMD (root /bin/bash /opt/tomcat/webapps/autoRestart.sh)
May 22 13:10:01 myApp/USR/SBIN/CRON[5532]: (root) CMD (root /bin/bash /opt/tomcat/webapps/autoRestart.sh)
```

When i run script manually like this, all works great

```
bash /opt/tomcat/webapps/autoRestart.sh
```

Where can i have a error?

Comment: What are the permissions of the script file?

Comment: Script file have all permissions to read, write and execute.

Comment: Can you try running this manually `/bin/bash /opt/tomcat/webapps/autoRestart.sh`?

Comment: When I run script manually like you write, all its fine.

Answer (score 0):

I bet wget is not in your path. (as run from cron)

Fully qualify the path to wget in the script and it'll probably work.